# Limit amount of words displayed from MySQL on a Twig page

Tags: symfony, twig

I wish to limit the amount of text displayed from a mysql statement. So for example, in my database I have a page where there are 1000 words contained in the content field, I want to be able to just display 200 of those words.

How can this be done using TWIG?

Cheers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like your are looking for the "truncate" filter.

In your `app/config/config.yml` add::

```
services:
 twig.extension.text:
     class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then you can do in your templates:

```
{{ var.foo | truncate(200) }}
{{ "Hello good Sir!" | truncate(4) }}
```

Comment: That's worked thank you. But may I ask why I have to add that code to the config.yml? I'm using the raw filter and I haven't needed to add any code to the the config.yml file?

Comment: Because the raw filter is a default filter build in Twig. Truncate is an extension. https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/text.rst